# Any idea what encryption is this

Tags: cryptography, encryption

I have the following encrypted strings with plain-text equivalents:

```
01b6e203 = to
8d777f38 = data
b068931c = name
c34487c9 = subject
0c83f57c = email
865c0c0b = i
```

any idea what kind of alogorithm/encryption/obfuscation can produce them? I don't have any idea, checked an hour on google, thought about crc32 but is not...the only find on google about encrypted string "8d777f38" is `Grid Account Username: **data**. Grid Account Identifier: **8d777f38**-5d3d-3ec8-815d-20f7496026dc`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the codes are all the same length, and the length seem too short to hold the data in the longer strings, it seems to be a hash code rather than encryption.

It could for example be the first for bytes of an MD5 hash, or it could be a CRC32 hash. You would simply have to get the hash code for the texts using the most common hashing algorithms, and see if you can find the codes in the result.

Comment: You are right, is first 8 characters from md5 hash: md5('data') -> 8d777f385d3dfec8815d20f7496026dc -> 8d777f38

Answer (score 0):

Note, that there is not just one CRC-32 code but a lot of usable generator polynomials exist, where one with very few coefficients is widely used for performance reasons.

It could also be a MAC (message authentication code, a sort of cipher block chaining encryption suppressing intermediate result blocks), where a four byte variant was sometimes used in environments, where every byte mattered, as in smart cards. Since a MAC involves a secret key:

1. only authorized parties knowing the key are able to verify it
2. brute force is still some hoework